# Force user to log in when making an in app purchase on iphone

Tags: iphone, security, parent, in-app-purchase

There are many reports of children being able to make in app purchases due to the fact that there is a 15 minute window of opportunity after logging into itunes where a user does not have to log into itunes again.  For instance, a parent downloads an application and then hands the phone to their child.  The child then has 15minutes to make in-app-purchases without having to enter a password.  And yes, I know there are parental control settings that can be set so that no in-app-purchases can be made.  But lets face it, most people are not involved enough to know about this.(Lets please not argue about how parents should be more involved, we all know they should be)  The real questions is:

Is there a way to force the iTunes login?  Or force a log out before running any in app purchase commands?

Answer (score 1):

No. The API to the Store Kit works at a higher level than tracking authentication. You have no programmatic control over it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could require that your app be in the foreground for at least 15 minutes before you allow in-app purchases. That would make it highly unlikely for the situation you describe to occur, with the major downside of making things much harder for your legitimate customers.